# Word 2019 and use of wildcards in Replace to remove newline

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards, replacement

I have used some of these wildcards in Replace from other threads on here with good results so far. But right now I am having difficulties with what appears to be an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key being pressed (newline) at each line, and the document is very long. The document itself is a .txt generated subtitles from Youtube video. I am trying to replace that newline after each 5-6 words.

I have also tried most of the Special Replace options down the box in the Replace menu and some other tweaks I have read about on here, but so far only managed to concatenate all the letters together.

I need to be able to format it as a normal text, i.e. like this post.

The file looks something like the following.

> because a ponzi scheme doesn't generate
>
> any wealth itself
>
> it must constantly bring in larger and
>
> larger groups of investors to keep
>
> functioning
>
> eventually no more new investors can be
>
> found
>
> or large numbers of previous investors

Comment: See these two Word MVP pages: http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CleanWebText.htm https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/cleanup_text.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear whether you want to eliminate all carriage returns or just extra ones between paragraphs. Below is a script that will eliminate extra ones, but the carriage return at the end of the paragraph stays.

Give us an update after you run it against your file.

```
Sub RemoveEmptyParagraphs()
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    'eliminate empty paragraphs
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "^13{2,}" ' look for 2
        .Replacement.Text = "^p" 'replace with 1, this is 508 acceptable
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    rng.Find.Execute Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll
    rng.Find.ClearFormatting
    rng.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked,replaced "^p" with "1", Thanks

Comment: @Tony - If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer.